# RPC binary request with Python

Tags: daemon, rpc, python, library

I am currently working with the Monero daemon RPC and have a little problem understanding the format of the binary request (`/get_o_indexes.bin` for example).

Does anyone have an example of how should I generate my binary request with Python's requests library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call the binary methods, you have to send raw binary data as an application/octet-stream in the request body and read the binary data sent back in the response body.

There's a StackOverflow answer that shows making binary requests using Python [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14448953/4272751). Quoting the requests library example:

```
import requests

data = 'test data'
res = requests.post(url='http://localhost:8888',
                data=data,
                headers={'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'})
```

Here you would replace `data` with the binary tx id (which is 32 bytes), wrapped as a Levin packet. A brief overview can be found [here](https://github.com/xmr-rs/xmr/blob/master/doc/levin.md).

For working out how to serialize the request data and deserialize the returned response data, you should start by looking in [this folder](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/tree/master/contrib/epee/include/storages).

Here is an annotated response for the interested:

```
0111010101010201        signature
01                      version
0c                      section
09 6f5f696e6465786573   field: string length then data: o_indexes
85                      type (uint64 | array flag)
08                      length 2 (0x08 >> 2)
aca87f0000000000        idx
ada87f0000000000        idx
06 737461747573         field: string length then data: status
0a                      type (string)
08                      length 2 (0x08 >> 2)
4f4b                    OK
09 756e74727573746564   field: string length then data: untrusted
0b                      type (bool)
00                      false
```

[Here](https://gist.github.com/jtgrassie/b466123d8a1eb9a62ca99a943809bba7) is a quick and dirty example of calling then parsing the response using Python.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tested your suggestion and still end up with a 404 not found.

I retrieved the binary from a tx id as a string of bit and used it in the post requestas data and still end up with a 404 not found.

This is my query:

`data = "".join(RPC_queries.to_bin(x) for x in utx);

res = requests.post(url='http://localhost:18081/get_o_indexes.bin', 
data=data,headers={'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'})`

Comment: Your conversion of a hex tx id to binary looks iffy - e.g. you want to use something like [binascii.unhexlify](http://docs.python.org/library/binascii.html#binascii.unhexlify).

Comment: Here is a [complete example](https://gist.github.com/jtgrassie/b466123d8a1eb9a62ca99a943809bba7) of calling the method and parsing the response using python.